# Try to configure AWS Documentdb but it's return Time out

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-documentdb

I am trying to configure DocumentDB in AWS but it give me "Time out error".

i checked security group,VPC everything are same as my EC2 instance.
After i try to connect the mongo db with mongo shell
there also its give me "time out" error.

Answer (score 1):

Check that the security group has an entry that allows traffic from itself on DocumentDB port.

Comment: +1 to herbertgoto's suggestion. You can find the step by step getting started instructions here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/get-started-guide.html